# JSON request in Odoo 12

Tags: python, xml, odoo-12

I have a problem executing a JSON in my custom module.
It is sent through a VPN connected to the Credit Bureau service, however the error it throws when executed is not clear.

When I press a button on the form, I get the following response error

> simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

In this case, *f360.buro* is a csv extension catalog hosted in the path */module/data/* from which it calls the user, password and url data.

```
 @api.multi
 def verifica_buro(self):
    for record in self:
    self.ensure_one()

    buro_site = self.env['f360.buro'].browse(1)

    apellidos = ""
    nombres = ""

    version = self.version
    no_ref_op = self.no_ref_op
    producto_req = self.producto_req
    id_buro = self.id_buro
    tipo_consulta = self.tipo_consulta
    tipo_contrato = self.tipo_contrato
    importe_contrato = self.importe_contrato
    idioma = self.idioma
    tipo_salida = self.tipo_salida
    apellido_paterno = self.lastname
    apellido_materno = self.lastname2
    primer_nombre = self.firstname
    fecha_nacimiento = self.birthdate_date
    rfc = self.vat
    prefijo = self.prefijo
    sufijo = self.sufijo
    nacionalidad = self.birth_country_id
    tipo_residencia = self.tipo_residencia
    no_lic_conducir = self.no_lic_conducir
    estado_civil = self.estado_civil
    sexo = self.gender
    no_ced_prof = self.no_ced_prof
    no_reg_elector = self.no_reg_elector
    clv_imp_otro_pais = self.clv_imp_otro_pais
    clv_otro_pais = self.clv_otro_pais
    no_dependientes = self.no_dependientes
    edad_dependientes = self.edad_dependientes
    direccion = self.street_name
    colonia_poblacion = self.colonia_id
    del_mun = self.municipio_id
    ciudad = self.localidad_id
    estado = self.state_id
    cp = self.zip_id
    fecha_residencia = self.fecha_residencia
    no_telefono = self.phone
    fax = self.fax
    tipo_domicilio = self.tipo_domicilio
    idn_esp_domicilio = self.idn_esp_domicilio
    nombre_empresa = self.nombre_empresa
    direccion_emp = self.direccion_emp
    direccion2_emp = self.direccion2_emp
    colonia_poblacion_emp = self.colonia_poblacion_emp
    del_mun_emp = self.del_mun_emp
    ciudad_emp = self.ciudad_emp
    estado_emp = self.estado_emp
    cp_emp = self.cp_emp
    no_telefono_emp = self.no_telefono_emp
    extension_emp = self.extension_emp
    fax_emp = self.fax_emp
    cargo = self.cargo
    fecha_contr = self.fecha_contr
    clv_mon_salario = self.clv_mon_salario
    salario = self.salario
    base_salarial = self.base_salarial
    no_empleado = self.no_empleado
    fecha_ult_dia_empleo = self.fecha_ult_dia_empleo
    cod_pais_emp = self.cod_pais_emp

    j_param = {
                "Consulta": {
                    "Personas": {
                        "Persona": {
                            "Encabezado": {
                                "Version": version,
                                "NumeroReferenciaOperador": no_ref_op,
                                "ProductoRequerido": producto_req,
                                "ClavePais": "MX",
                                "IdentificadorBuro": id_buro,
                                "ClaveUsuario": buro_site.name,
                                "Password": buro_site.password,
                                "TipoConsulta": tipo_consulta,
                                "TipoContrato": tipo_contrato,
                                "ClaveUnidadMonetaria": "MX",
                                "ImporteContrato": importe_contrato,
                                "Idioma": idioma,
                                "TipoSalida": tipo_salida
                            },
                            "Nombre": {
                                "ApellidoPaterno": apellido_paterno,
                                "ApellidoMaterno": apellido_materno,
                                "ApellidoAdicional": "",
                                "PrimerNombre": primer_nombre,
                                "SegundoNombre": "",
                                "FechaNacimiento": fecha_nacimiento,
                                "RFC": rfc,
                                "Prefijo": prefijo,
                                "Sufijo": sufijo,
                                "Nacionalidad": "MX",
                                "Residencia": tipo_residencia,
                                "NumeroLicenciaConducir": no_lic_conducir,
                                "EstadoCivil": estado_civil,
                                "Sexo": sexo,
                                "NumeroCedulaProfesional": no_ced_prof,
                                "NumeroRegistroElectoral": no_reg_elector,
                                "ClaveImpuestosOtroPais": clv_imp_otro_pais,
                                "ClaveOtroPais": clv_otro_pais,
                                "NumeroDependientes": no_dependientes,
                                "EdadesDependientes": edad_dependientes
                            },
                            "Domicilios": {
                                "Domicilio": {
                                    "Direccion1": direccion,
                                    "Direccion2": "",
                                    "ColoniaPoblacion": colonia_poblacion,
                                    "DelegacionMunicipio": del_mun,
                                    "Ciudad": ciudad,
                                    "Estado": estado,
                                    "CP": cp,
                                    "FechaResidencia": fecha_residencia,
                                    "NumeroTelefono": no_telefono,
                                    "Extension": "",
                                    "Fax": fax,
                                    "TipoDomicilio": tipo_domicilio,
                                    "IndicadorEspecialDomicilio": idn_esp_domicilio,
                                    "CodPais": "MX"
                                }
                            },
                            "Empleos": {
                                "Empleo": {
                                    "NombreEmpresa": nombre_empresa,
                                    "Direccion1": direccion_emp,
                                    "Direccion2": direccion2_emp,
                                    "ColoniaPoblacion": colonia_poblacion_emp,
                                    "DelegacionMunicipio": del_mun_emp,
                                    "Ciudad": ciudad_emp,
                                    "Estado": estado_emp,
                                    "CP": cp_emp,
                                    "NumeroTelefono": no_telefono_emp,
                                    "Extension": extension_emp,
                                    "Fax": fax_emp,
                                    "Cargo": cargo,
                                    "FechaContratacion": fecha_contr,
                                    "ClaveMonedaSalario": clv_mon_salario,
                                    "Salario": salario,
                                    "BaseSalarial": base_salarial,
                                    "NumeroEmpleado": no_empleado,
                                    "FechaUltimoDiaEmpleo": fecha_ult_dia_empleo,
                                    "CodPais": cod_pais_emp
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    json_data = requests.post(buro_site.url, data=j_param)

    j_data = json_data.json()
    j_status = json_data.status_code
    j_headers = json_data.headers
```

Answer (score 0):

Check response data-body, 
In most of the cases, this error is due to non-JSON conforming quoting

Comment: thank you very much friend, that was the problem, I had nowhere to receive the JSON delivery information.